# XML - Search for value in XML file

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I have a script that uses `xmlstarlet` to edit a XML file using this:

```
sudo xmlstarlet ed -L --omit-decl \
-s '//configuration' -t elem -n "property" -v '' \
-s '//configuration/property[last()]' -t elem -n "name" -v "this.is.a.node" \
-s '//configuration/property[last()]' -t elem -n "value" -v "value.for.above.node" \
-s '//configuration' -t elem -n "property" -v '' \
-s '//configuration/property[last()]' -t elem -n "name" -v "this.is.another.node" \
-s '//configuration/property[last()]' -t elem -n "value" -v "value.for.second" \
/path/to/file
```

Which results in this:

```
    <configuration>
    ....
    ....
    ....
     <property>
        <name>this.is.a.node</name>
        <value>value.for.above.node</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>this.is.another.node</name>
        <value>value.for.second</value>
      </property>
    </configuration>
```

However the problem is that IF the script is run more than once, I get the above block added again. I would like to avoid that but I am not sure how to go about it. I cant find anything on the documentation that supports conditional statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`count`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch04.html#idm47989546279904)

```
if [[ $(xmlstarlet sel -t -v "count(/configuration/property[name='this.is.a.node'])" /paht/to/file/xml) -eq 1 ]];then echo "there"; else echo "nope"; fi
```